# Objects and Javascript: How do I add new values to a newly constructed object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have constructed a new object from an array of objects to allow me to pass data in. It will condense the array of objects to a smaller array of objects that can be used for data visualisation easier than before.

I'm simply stuck.

I've got this far, but im  caught now and can't figure out how to proceed.

This is all the code:

```
window.onload = function () {
    console.log('data', data)
    const arrObj = data;

    let mapPlaces = arrObj.map(i => i.place_name)
    let uniquePlaces = [...new Set(mapPlaces)];

    console.log('2place_name', arrObj.map(i => i.place_name))
    console.log('uniquePlaces', uniquePlaces)


    const newObj = uniquePlaces.map(v => {
        return ({
            location: v,
            year: {
                '10': '',
                '11': '',
                '12': '',
                '13': '',
                '14': '',
                '15': '',
                '16': '',
                '17': '',
                '18': '',
                '19': '',
                '95': '',
                '96': '',
                '97': '',
                '98': '',
                '99': '',
                '00': '',
                '01': '',
                '02': '',
                '03': '',
                '04': '',
                '05': '',
                '06': '',
                '07': '',
                '08': '',
                '09': ''
            }
        })
    })
    const finalObj = newObj.map(i => {
        // console.log('i', i)
        const result = arrObj.filter(j => {
            // console.log('j', j)
            if (j.place_name === i.location) {
                const newPriceAdded = (
                    newObj.year[j.year] = j.price
                )
                console.log('newPriceAdded', newPriceAdded)
                return newPriceAdded
            }
        })
        const slicedResult = result.slice(0, 25)
        return slicedResult;
    })

    console.log('finalObj', finalObj)
    const myJSON = JSON.stringify(finalObj);
    return document.getElementById("jsonDiv").innerHTML = myJSON;


}
```

Heres the data:

```
const data = [
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "95",
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "96",
        "price": 103.19
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "97",
        "price": 99.81
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "98",
        "price": 102.7
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "99",
        "price": 103.43
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "00",
        "price": 103.91
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "01",
        "price": 108.71
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "02",
        "price": 115.59
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "03",
        "price": 125.77
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "04",
        "price": 140.02
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "05",
        "price": 161.66
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "06",
        "price": 183.55
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "07",
        "price": 191.6
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "08",
        "price": 195.04
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "09",
        "price": 193.69
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "10",
        "price": 186.51
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "11",
        "price": 186.19
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "12",
        "price": 185.14
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "13",
        "price": 185.2
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "14",
        "price": 181.7
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "15",
        "price": 186.88
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "16",
        "price": 190.23
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "17",
        "price": 193.94
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "18",
        "price": 202.51
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Albany-Schenectady-Troy, NY",
        "year": "19",
        "price": 206.5
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "95",
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "96",
        "price": 101.14
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "97",
        "price": 97.59
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "98",
        "price": 104.98
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "99",
        "price": 109.23
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "00",
        "price": 107.62
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "01",
        "price": 116.33
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "02",
        "price": 123.51
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "03",
        "price": 127.99
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "04",
        "price": 131.27
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "05",
        "price": 138.92
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "06",
        "price": 154.53
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "07",
        "price": 166.31
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "08",
        "price": 179.47
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "09",
        "price": 181.03
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "10",
        "price": 178.4
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "11",
        "price": 169.56
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "12",
        "price": 167.02
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "13",
        "price": 173.3
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "14",
        "price": 168.92
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "15",
        "price": 166.03
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "16",
        "price": 166.58
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "17",
        "price": 165.71
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "18",
        "price": 173.75
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Binghamton, NY",
        "year": "19",
        "price": 177.04
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "95",
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "96",
        "price": 105.5
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "97",
        "price": 103.4
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "98",
        "price": 105.8
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "99",
        "price": 106.29
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "00",
        "price": 102.95
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "01",
        "price": 109.39
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "02",
        "price": 113.54
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "03",
        "price": 117.93
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "04",
        "price": 123.44
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "05",
        "price": 131.73
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "06",
        "price": 136.78
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "07",
        "price": 140.14
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "08",
        "price": 143.76
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "09",
        "price": 147.7
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "10",
        "price": 146.41
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "11",
        "price": 147.12
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "12",
        "price": 149.02
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "13",
        "price": 150.44
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "14",
        "price": 155.2
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "15",
        "price": 159.21
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "16",
        "price": 164.4
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "17",
        "price": 173.95
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "18",
        "price": 185.39
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Buffalo-Cheektowaga, NY",
        "year": "19",
        "price": 198.55
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "95",
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "96",
        "price": 102.8
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "97",
        "price": 98.72
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "98",
        "price": 104.62
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "99",
        "price": 107.3
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "00",
        "price": 109.59
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "01",
        "price": 117.95
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "02",
        "price": 119.72
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "03",
        "price": 125.08
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "04",
        "price": 126.2
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "05",
        "price": 133.62
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "06",
        "price": 139.22
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "07",
        "price": 147.15
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "08",
        "price": 149.48
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "09",
        "price": 157.64
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "10",
        "price": 157.95
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "11",
        "price": 158.09
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "12",
        "price": 163.78
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "13",
        "price": 160.09
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "14",
        "price": 162.26
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "15",
        "price": 166.42
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "16",
        "price": 158.15
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "17",
        "price": 168.35
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "18",
        "price": 168.08
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Elmira, NY",
        "year": "19",
        "price": 169.32
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Glens Falls, NY",
        "year": "95",
        "price": 100
    },
    {
        "place_name": "Glens Falls, NY",
        "year": "96",
        "price": 96.64
    }
]
```

I've had to remove some line to fit into the body limit. Do as you need to editing.
I need the object to look like this:

```
{
location: v,
            year: {
                '10': '',
                '11': '',
                '12': '',
                '13': '',
                '14': '',
                '15': '',
                '16': '',
                '17': '',
                '18': '',
                '19': '',
                '95': '',
                '96': '',
                '97': '',
                '98': '',
                '99': '',
                '00': '',
                '01': '',
                '02': '',
                '03': '',
                '04': '',
                '05': '',
                '06': '',
                '07': '',
                '08': '',
                '09': ''
            }
}
```

One for each location.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this question might be breaking some stackoverflow rules, but anyway, here's the code to get the data you want:

```
const dataByPlaceName = data.reduce((a, place) => {
  // create record if it doesn't exist yet
  a[place.place_name] = a[place.place_name] || {
    location: place.place_name,
    year: {}
  };

  // update record with price-by-year data
  a[place.place_name].year[place.year] = place.price;
  return a;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(dataByPlaceName);
```

Comment: I think there was something in the rules about questions being "too specific" (and hence, the answer is usually of little help to others). But i'm not sure. I didn't downvote it anyway. Good luck!